# Where is python's documentation located on a Mac?

Tags: python, documentation

So far I've been using Python.org to find the docs. But when there is no internet connection, I'd like to browse the local documentation in a browser.

The question is: where is it?

I checked the framework bundle and there was nothing there except PyObjC docs:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

and couldn't find anything under ~/Library or /usr/share/doc either.

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: It comes installed with OS X.

Comment: I use the built-in python OS X. Too bad there is no Mac IDE like Xcode for Python that allows you to view the doc set.

Comment: The funny thing is, Xcode _does_ have support for Python (although most of it is hidden in 5.x), including being able to look up Python documentation, and it even gets the Python syntax right in Quick Help… except that there is no doc set you can install for it to look in. Someone figured out how to massage the Python docs into an Xcode 4.0 doc set, but as far as I know it was never updated for newer versions.

Comment: Meanwhile, there are plenty of good Mac IDEs for Python that can view the docs—Eclipse PyDev, PyCharm, etc.

Comment: @abarnert , wow, I didn't know Xcode supports syntax highlight and word completion for Python. It's definitely a functional editor but can't find how to view docs with it. I tried PyCharm. It only shows quick-doc instead of the help pages you get on Python.org. But anyways, I've found my answer. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @kakyo: To get Xcode to view docs, you have to create an Xcode docset. And as far as I know, Apple stopped explaining how to do that after Xcode 3.2, so presumably you'd have to reverse-engineer the Xcode 5 format. (And then, of course, you'd have to build something that turns the Python help _into_ that format. (The doc source is designed to be processed into a variety of different formats, so adding another one shouldn't be nearly as hard as figuring out what that format is in the first place…)

Comment: @abamert: Thank you for the tip! Now I know docset is the only way out. We've been using doxygen to generate docset for C/C++ projects for a couple of years and it still works with Xcode5. Looks like it works with Python too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the [`pydoc` command line tool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) (which provides documentation from the source docstrings and introspection only), there is no documentation installed by OS X.

You can [download the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/download.html) from Python.org instead; PDF (in A4 or Letter formatted pages), HTML and plain text options are provided there.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know pydoc! This is useful.